# Music library volume leveling

Tags: sound, music, ipod

**Preface**

I listen to my music on an iPod Classic in my car and in the past I got frustrated that the volume between songs would be radically different forcing me to adjust the volume on my iPod (or blow out my ear drums). At the time my entire collection was on my Windows PC so I did some research and found MP3Gain. After running MP3Gain on my library and syncing my iPod everything (seemed) to be the same (perceived) volume. But that all changed when I moved my music collection to an Ubuntu based media server.

**The Problem**

Now that all my media is on my media server any new music I add isn't the same (perceived) volume as the rest of my media (when playing through my iPod). What I'm hoping to find is something that will make my music files sound like they are at the same volume on my iPod (basically do what MP3Gain did).

**What I've Tried**

I've tried to do as much research as I can regarding the issue but I'm a giant noob in regards to audio and haven't come up with a whole lot. I know MP3Gain was on Ubuntu but was removed due to it's lack of a maintainer.

I came across [sox](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man1/sox.1.html) but I couldn't quite figure out what I'd need to do to solve my problem.

I've installed and run collectiongain (part of [rgain](https://bitbucket.org/fk/rgain)) on my music collection but that didn't seem (maybe it did and I can't tell?) to solve my problem either.

**Notes**

- As mentioned I'm a noob when it comes to audio so if I'm barking up the wrong tree or just plain wrong I'm more than willing to learn what is correct
- I'd say my Linux/Ubuntu skill level is somehwere between novice and intermediate but again I'm willing to learn what I need to
- My media server is a headless server running Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Any help on this is greatly appreciated!

**Edit**

There are a lot of tutorials out there for normalizing audio and from my understanding that's not what I want and not what MP3 Audio does (correct me if I'm wrong). I'm looking for a solution that does **not** re-encode my files and does **not** do Peak Normalization (ReplayGain seems to be what I'm looking for). The proposed duplicate question (again, from what I understand) does peak normalization and re-encodes the files.

Answer (score 1):

I have been messing around with it, but yes, it seems that [replaygain](https://bitbucket.org/fk/rgain) can do what you want.

First, install `replaygain`:

```
sudo apt install python-rgain
```

Then you can go to the base folder of your MP3 files

```
cd /path/to/base/of/MP3/files
```

The manpage states to run

```
replaygain filename.mp3
```

Or you can run the following command that will go through all subfolders finding all your MP3 files and then adding the `replaygain` album gain to each found file:

```
find . -type f -name '*.mp3' | while read musicname; do replaygain "$musicname"; done
```

Sit back and watch `replaygain` do its thing.

Hope this helps!